# Number of spanning trees on a complete graph without a tree?

Tags: graph-theory

Say we have the complete graph on $n$ vertices, $K_n$, and a spanning tree $T$ of it. Can we say something about the number of spanning trees on the graph formed by removing the edges of $T$ from the edges of $K_n$?

Comment: Do you remove all the edges at the same time?

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides yes

Comment: Then the remaining graph won't have any edges.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides we remove only the edges of one spanning tree

Comment: you're right. I missread.

Comment: Special case – the removed tree is a star (one vertex of degree $n-1$, adjacent to all the other $n-1$ vertices), then what's left is just $K_{n-1}$ plus an isolated point, so no spanning trees.